# Laravel testing dontSee negates English text

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I'm testing a Laravel app and need to make sure a text is NOT present on a page, easy enough. I use `dontSee` but I get a surprising error

**Code**

```
public function testSuccessfulSignupActivated(){

    $this->visit('/signup?activate=true')
        ->type('username', 'name')
        ->type('test@mail.com', 'mail')
        ->type('password', 'password')
        ->type('password', 'password_confirm')
        ->type('Philip', 'first_name')
        ->type('Fry', 'last_name')
        ->select('Freelancer', 'profile')
        ->check('licensecheck')->press('Create new account')
        ->seePageIs('/user')
        ->dontSee('A validation e-mail has been sent to your e-mail address.') ;
}
```

**Error**

Failed asserting that '...' does not match PCRE pattern **A validation e-mail does not have been sent to your e-mail address**.

It seems to have negated the English sentence I passed which is not at all what I want to do, just to be sure I'm not crazy I checked my source code and the text is "A validation e-mail has been sent to your e-mail address"

`dontSeeText` has the same effect and `dontSeeInElement` passes the test with the text on the page (false positive)

Comment: @tam sorry that was a typo

Comment: @tam no that one's verbatim ! I don't understand where it comes from, checked my source code and everything

Comment: @tam I have another test that checks for the presence of that string but I'm using a filter on phpunit to run just this test case in isolation

Comment: is there anywhere in your application or tests that contains this 'does not have been' string? are you using an editor that you can do a search in all files for that string

Comment: @tam yeah that's exactly what I did, searched all the files in that project :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a side effect in PHPUnit.

Currently, up through Laravel 5.2.22, Laravel's `dontSee()` test uses the PHPUnit `assertNotRegExp()` test. When this test fails, the message it returns attempts to negate certain words in the text that was being checked. You can see the list of words [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/4.1.6/src/Framework/Constraint/Not.php#L85-L114).

In your case, it replaced the word `has` with `does not have`.

There is actually a [pull request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/12557) in Laravel to address this issue, and it has already been merged in. However, there hasn't been a new tagged release since it was merged. I'm assuming the next tagged version will include this update (Laravel 5.2.23). Once this update is included in a tagged release, you should be able to `composer update`, and your validation message will look much nicer.